# wc_get_template_part filter not working

Tags: filters

I am trying to replace the content-single-product.php template file from within a plugin. I am trying to use the `wc_get_template_part` filter to replace the content however the filter just doesn't seem to fire. This is the most basic code I've got to test for the filter working. I have confirmed that `error_log` does work by including a test line outside of this filter code.

```
add_filter('wc_get_template_part', function ($template, $slug, $name) {

    error_log('wc_get_template_part');

    return $template;

}, 10, 4);
```

I have tried from within a Theme and a Plugin, neither work. What am I missing/what else can I try?

Comment: You're telling it you're passing 4 parameters but then only passing 3. Change `,10, 4` to `,10, 4` and see if that fixes the issue.

Comment: @PatJ ah missed that one. It doesn't work when tchanging 3 -> 4 unfortunately.